# GCP | Cannot delete a cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm getting this error trying to delete

```
Error: Error waiting for deleting GKE cluster:
(1)
(1)
(1)
(1) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx'
(2) retry budget exhausted (5 attempts): Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.routes.list' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx'
(2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/global/firewalls/gke-test-38003a6d-all'
(3) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/global/firewalls/gke-test-38003a6d-master'
(4) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.firewalls.delete' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/global/firewalls/gke-test-38003a6d-vms'
(5) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-test-global-7a297850-grp'
(6) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instanceGroupManagers.delete' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-test-istio-59af0ad5-grp'
(2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.removePeering' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/global/networks/vpc-net'
(2) Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.subnetworks.get' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxxx/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/vpc-net'.
```

It seems some permission has been deleted, I tried to create a new service account but didn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a while I just disabled the API in that way:

```
gcloud services disable container.googleapis.com --project myproject
```

And then enable again using:

```
gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com --project myproject
```

This restores the permissions to be able to delete again.

Then no issues to delete the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use another account with higher privileges?
If you an admin of the current project you should be able to re-assign necessary project permissions for managing GKE.

Comment: I'm using mine as a Owner but still same issue

Comment: I got fixed disabling the container.googleapis.com and enabling it again.. finally